# Adding a tag_ID column into Categories inside the admin dashboard?

Tags: php, functions

So right now there are four columns when you navigate to Posts > Categories (or your custom Taxonomy):

Name  | Description | Slug | Count

I'm working with taxonomy `term_id` a lot, so I need to see the id column as well.

Is there a way to add a Sortable ID column?

I was looking, but couldn't find it.

If anyone have made this for themselves, I would really appreciate if someone could share the functions.php code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

1. Use the [`manage_<screen ID>_columns` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/) to add the "ID" column.

   Example for the default `category` taxonomy where `<screen ID>` is `edit-category` — for other taxonomies, it would be `edit-<taxonomy>` like `edit-post_tag`:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'manage_edit-category_columns', 'my_manage_edit_category_columns' );
   function my_manage_edit_category_columns( $columns ) {
       // Add the "ID" column.
       $columns['term_id'] = 'ID';
       // .. add other columns, if you want to.

       return $columns;
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`manage_<screen ID>_sortable_columns` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/) to make the "ID" column be sortable.

   Example for the default `category` taxonomy (the screen ID format is the same as above):

   ```php
   add_filter( 'manage_edit-category_sortable_columns', 'my_manage_edit_category_sortable_columns' );
   function my_manage_edit_category_sortable_columns( $sortable_columns ) {
       // Add the "ID" column.
       $sortable_columns['term_id'] = 'term_id';
       // .. add other columns, if you want to.

       return $sortable_columns;
   }
   ```
3. Use the [`manage_<taxonomy>_custom_column` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-taxonomy_custom_column/) to display the actual term ID in the "ID" column.

   Example for the default `category` taxonomy:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'manage_category_custom_column', 'my_manage_category_custom_column', 10, 3 );
   function my_manage_category_custom_column( $content, $column_name, $term_id ) {
       switch ( $column_name ) {
           case 'term_id':
               $content = $term_id;
               break;
       }

       return $content;
   }
   ```

That's all, but for sorting by other fields than the `term_id`, you would need to manually filter the terms query args, e.g. using the [`get_terms_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/) or the [`parse_term_query` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_term_query/).

Comment: Thanks! I have change the category to my custom taxonomy name and it worked! Thanks for you help and time spent, Sally CJ!